# Datastax Driver Mapping ORDER BY ASC/DESC

Tags: cassandra, mapping, cql, datastax-java-driver

Suppose the next Cassandra ColumnFamily:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    A text,
    B text,
    time timestamp,
    PRIMARY KEY ((A, B), time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

I need to execute the next CQL 3 query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE A='aaaaa' AND B='bbbbb' ORDER BY time DESC
```

(which works fine in CQL console) by using Datastax Driver Mapping (cassandra-driver-mapping-2.1.6). My Accesor is the next one:

```
@Accessor
public interface myTableAccesor {  

    @Query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE A=:A AND B=:B ORDER BY time :order")
    Result<myTable> getAllByKey(@Param("A") String A, @Param("B") String B, @Param("order") String order);
}
```

But I get the next Exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:136 missing EOF at ':' (...=:B ORDER BY time [:]order)
```

when I execute:

```
myTableAccesor accessor = manager.createAccessor(myTableAccesor.class);
```

However, the LIMIT case:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE A=:A AND B=:B LIMIT :max")
        Result<myTable> getAllByKey(@Param("A") String A, @Param("B") String B, @Param("max") String max);
```

works properly.

I think that the problem is related with String type (maybe some ' character?) But I'm not sure. Is there any way to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not valid CQL to bind on the ORDER BY direction in a Prepared Statement (which is what Accessors use) like you can with the LIMIT.  As a workaround you can create two separate accessors:

```java
@Query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE A=:A AND B=:B ORDER BY time DESC")
Result<myTable> getAllByKeyDesc(@Param("A") String A, @Param("B") String B);

@Query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE A=:A AND B=:B ORDER BY time ASC")
Result<myTable> getAllByKeyAsc(@Param("A") String A, @Param("B") String B);
```

Comment: thanks @Andy. This is my current solution, but I wanted to reduce the number of queries ( to a half :))

Comment: CQL doesn't allow parameterization of the ORDER BY clause so the driver doesn't really have a way to address this.

Comment: @AlexPopescu, I think that you can parametrize ORDER BY by clustering order and the reverse of that one (at least in [CQL3](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#selectStmt) )

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the protocol doesn't allow `SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY fld ?` (passing the order by clause as a parameter).

Comment: Ok @AlexPopescu, I understand you now, your are saying the same as Andy response, isn't it? Thanks.